# Post Per Page not working

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

This function is here to display a custom post type (frontpage_items) on the home page. It used to be working, but somewhere along the way in one of the WP updates, it broke. Now it only displays one of the 4 posts and breaks the footer.

I have got it to stop breaking my footer by just doing 1 post_per_page as opposed to the all (-1). But I really need to get all 4 of them back.

PS. this was a site I had built by an offshore resource...

Here is the code for the function:

```
function frontpage_items_init() {
    $args = array(
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => false,
        'label' => 'Frontpage Items',
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor')
    );

    register_post_type( 'frontpage_items', $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'frontpage_items_init' );
add_action('woo_content_after', 'show_frontpage_items', 9999);

function show_frontpage_items() {

    if(is_front_page()) {

        $f_posts = get_posts(array(
            'post_type' => 'frontpage_items',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'posts_per_page' => -1
        ));

        if(count($f_posts) = 0) {
            global $post;
            foreach ($f_posts as $fp) {
                setup_postdata($fp); 
                ?>

                <div class="frontpage_item <?php echo $fp->post_name; ?>_wrap">
                    <div class="wrap">
                        <div class="frontpage_item_body">
                            <?php the_content(); ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>

                <?php
            }
        }
    }

    wp_reset_query();
}
```

Comment: Does it help if you change count($f_posts) = 0 into count($f_posts) > 0 in the bottom if-statement?

Comment: Unfortunately it didnt help... :/

Answer (score 0):

Multiple things I see wrong here that could be causing your issue. First, you are attempting to assign a value from the posts count as opposed to check it via a comparison operator.

`if( count($f_posts) = 0 )`

should be something along the lines of

`if( count($f_posts) != 0 ) //not equal to 0`

The second issue is that Wordpress requires you to use the global `$post` variable when iterating through posts with your method.

```
foreach( $f_posts as $fp )
    setup_postdata($fp);
```

should be

```
foreach( $f_posts as $post )
    setup_postdata($post);
```

For more information, see the docs on [`get_posts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts)